# Why does my brake keep pinging out and almost killing me?

Tags: brakes

My back brake (top picture) is clamped down, as it should be. The quick release on the front won't stay down. I have tried loosening the cables, tightening them, nothing works. As you can see in the gif at the bottom, it keeps springing back.

I've decided enough is enough. I braked hard while going down a hill and the front brake just pinged open. Not good. I didn't get hurt, but it's only a matter of time.

Why is this? What can I do? just get a new front mech?

[image: Good][image: Bad]

Comment: The cable is somehow routed improperly.  I can't make out from the image exactly what's wrong, but when the lever is pushed in the cable should run straight down, not angle out like that.  I'm guessing it's hanging up on the end of the pivot bolt.

Comment: Dirt under the ratchet? Clean and blow with compressed air (if available).

Comment: @DanielRHicks  That comment looks totally like an answer to me.    I agree - the inner wire should not have that angle on it to pull sideways.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the quick release mechanism used when removing the tyre to open the caliper a little wider.

It looks broken? - it should be tucked under in line with the pull of the cable. Since it isn't the cable is actually pulling the release open as you brake.

You might be able to temporarily remedy it by leaving it in the open position and pulling the cable tighter. You would however lose the use of the quick release. Probably not a great idea to run it like this - since the cable will be pulling on the fixing nut at a strange angle.
Best replace with a new caliper.

Comment: I wouldn't leave it in the open position, route the cable properly would be much better.